# Make textview match height of alert dialog

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I want to make a clean looking alertdialog were the textview matches the height on the alertdialog.

```
final Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
                TextView msg = new TextView(this);
                msg.setText("The winner is Player " + Players.intFromPlayers(player));
                msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                msg.setLayoutParams(params);
                builder.setView(msg);
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        finish();
                    }
                })

                .show();
```

[image]

Comment: how do you set params?

Comment: @nr4bt: tried "msg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));" as suggested below.

Comment: You can't, because `AlertDialog` have dinamically height, that is sized depending of its child's size. You could especify the height of your AlertDialog and then especify your text's height.

But why do you want to match the height of your TextView to the height of your `AlertDialog`, sice the size of the text is done by `android:textSize?`

Comment: Ok, so I should calc a size of the text so it looks good on all displays and then the alertdialog will just change dynamical? :) *edit* Ok, that worked. Too bad it couldnt be as slim as I wanted it. :S

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pretty good looking alertdialog, you can consider putting padding as well since AlertDialog height is dynamically created.

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
```

you'll have 20dp space between top and your text

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of your text view to match_parent:

```
msg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't fix it. :S